# Regex for hours, min and optionally Section with more possible formats

Tags: regex, datetime-parsing, time-format

I need to create regex that allows below time values:
single digit or double digits and optionally second.

All possible combination for single digit of Hour/Minute/Second:

```
hh:mm:ss AM/PM
h:m:s AM/PM
hh:m:s AM/PM
h:mm:s AM/PM
h:m:ss
```

Accepted values are:

```
11:12:59 AM
1:2:3 PM
1:22:30 pm
01:2:00 PM
1:3 PM
```

I tried some possible combination from,
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s06.html like:

```
^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?( )[AaPp][Mm]
```

But it doesn't work as expected above.

Can you please correct me on above sample or some other regex that allows above possible values.

Comment: For which format(s) does it not work as expected?  Is the `AM`/`PM` required and, if so, how come the last format (`h:m:ss`) is lacking it?  Are you using this to _validate_ or _parse_ input?  Your list of formats is not being rendered as I think you intended, though I think they could be summed up as simply `h:m` and `h:m:s` (pending the answer about `AM`/`PM`) because, of course, those accept two-digit components when needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work as expected"? if you see this link https://regex101.com/r/TiKfCf/1 , you can see that the pattern matches all the accepted values you have given. Post your code and the inputs in which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex in the question doesn't make the am/pm optional.
And the minutes/seconds can be 1 group that occurs 1 to 2 times.

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[:][0-5]?[0-9]){1,2}(?:[ ][APap][Mm])?$
```

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/TiKfCf/2)